# AngularJS nested directive $pristine and $dirty settings

Tags: angularjs, nested, directive

I'm having issues with a directive I am writing.

Within the directive's template there is also another element directive.

Essentially the outer directive is a decorator for the inner, adding more functionality..

The issue that I am having is that the $pristine and $dirty values are not being set as I would have expected.

I have amended the fiddle below to demonstrate a similar scenario..
(Code follows:)

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
<h3>rn-stepper demo (3/5)</h3>
Model value : {{ rating }}<br>
<hr>
<div ng-model="rating" rn-stepper></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('demo', [])

.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.rating = 42;      
})

.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel"></input>'
    };
})

.directive('rnStepper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            value: '=ngModel'
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="decrement()">-</button>' +
                  '<div>{{ value }}</div>' +
                  '<button ng-click="increment()">+</button>' +
                  '<test ng-model="value"></test>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.increment = function() {
                scope.value++;
            }
            scope.decrement = function() {
                scope.value--;
            }
        }
    };
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qqqspj7o/

The model is shared as expected and when I change the value in either the text input or using the slider, the binding works - however if I update the value in the text input, only the text input is marked as ng-dirty - the element directive itself remains as ng-pristine as does the outer div.

I don't understand why this is and the values are not propagated to the element? Is that expected behaviour - if so, how do I propagate the ng-dirty etc values to the element directive and the outer div..

**Note: I can only use Angular v 1.2.x as the code needs to be compatible with IE8.**

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in directives you should avoid `=value` binding, and work directly with [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

This topic is a bit complicated for discussion here, but there are many great tutorias on the web I point you to this one: 
[using ngModelController](http://www.chroder.com/2014/02/01/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/) it explains basics of working with ngModel and also tells bit about decorators.

When you work directly with `ngModel` you can set validity and state (dirty/touched/pristine) directly in your code, you can also set model value via `$setViewValue()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately I can't set dirty state using ngModelController as I'm restricted to an old version of AngularJS (1.2.28) as I need to support IE8. (Edited question to include this). AngularJS 1.2.28 doesn't have the $setDirty() method on ngModelController...

Comment: Quick and _ugly_ fix may be to `$scope.$watch` on `ngModel.$dirty` and manually setting/removing `ng-dirty` class using `ng-class`.